# Match names on a vector and give values of 0/1 on a new column of dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to loop over a dataframe and if names on a specific column match my list, give them value of '1' in a new column and if they don't give them '0'.

This is the code, I have so far.

```
Class<-rep(NA,600) # Create a vector of NA of length 600
data[ , "Class"] <- Class # Adding a column with NA named "Class"
check = c("RUTH","TAM111","WESLEY","FREEMAN") #Check if data$Name matches these
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
 for (j in data){
  if (data$Name ==check[j]){ 
   data$Class <- 1
  } else {
   data$Class <- 0
  } 
 }
}
```

I am getting this error.

the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

```
Error in if (data$Name == check[j]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The `if` is throwing the error: `data$Name` is a vector and the equality `==` is designed for single (not vectorized) values. Try `data$Name[i]`. Your code has several issues on the `fors` which show a lack of understanding on how loops work: you might want to try a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ifelse` and `%in%` to conditional add the new column:

```
data$Class <- ifelse(data$Name %in% check, 1, 0)
```

Comment: or more compactly `data$Class <- data$name %in% check*1`

Answer (score 1):

Getting your head around how `R` handles vectors can be tricky, but will save you from writing lots of `for` loops. Try this:

```
#create dataframe:
check <- c("RUTH","TAM111","WESLEY","FREEMAN")
data <- data.frame(name=sample(c(check, letters), replace=T, size=50), class=rep(NA,50)) # Create a vector of NA of length 600
head(data)
     name class
1       e    NA
2       m    NA
3       g    NA
4  TAM111    NA
5 FREEMAN    NA
6       m    NA

# substitute values:
data$class[data$name %in% check] <- '1'
data$class[!data$name %in% check] <- '0'
head(data)
     name class
1       e     0
2       m     0
3       g     0
4  TAM111     1
5 FREEMAN     1
6       m     0
```